# Referir uma tabela noutra base de dados no mesmo server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou a fazer uma aplicativo em `C#` e `.NET Core` (`ASP.NET Core MVC`) que utiliza a `EntityFrameworkCore` e na `Connection String` acesso a uma base de dados, digamos DB1, e consigo ler as tabelas desta base de dados programaticamente.

A connection string é:

```
Server=MY\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DB1;User ID=Me;
    Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Mas, no mesmo server tenho outras bases de dados, digamos a DB2. Na minha app precisava de aceder às duas bases de dados. Assim o código do Modelo é:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyApp.Models
{
    // modelo das várias tabelas na DB1...

    [Table("tMyTable")]      // esta tabela está na DB2!
    public class MyModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        // ...
    }
}
```

O modelo para aceder aos dados é:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class appDataContext : DbContext
{
    private AppFeatures features { get; set; }

    private DbContextOptions<appDataContext> opt { get; set; }

    private DbSet<MyModel> tbl { get; set; }

    public appDataContext(
        DbContextOptions<appDataContext> options, 
        AppFeatures _features 
    )
        : base(options)
    {
        opt = options;
        features = _features;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(features.ConnectionString);

    private IEnumerable<MyModel> _fcRetrieveUser(int id)
        => tbl.Where(l => l.ID == id);

    // acesso a outras tabelas
}
```

Claro que este código não funciona, pois a `tMyTable` não está apontada na `Connection String`, como é que posso referir esta tabela na base de dados correta sem criar outra `Connection String` e utilizando este esqueleto, e sem utilizar pura SQL (Raw SQL)?

Já tentei pôr `[Table("DB2.dbo.tMyTable")]` ou `[Table("tMyTable", Schema="DB2.dbo")]` mas nenhuma funcionou.

Há algum atributo que possa usar para referir a base de dados `DB2`, como por exemplo `Database`?

Comment: Não tem como! Cada camada ORM possui a sua própria conexão a partir disso as entidades funcionam de acordo com essa conexão ... Crie outra camada de Persistencia e cada um cuida das suas tabelas / entidades. Porque complicar?

Comment: Quer dizer que tenho de utilizar SQL cru (tipo `SELECT ... FROM DB2.dbo.tMyTable`) ou criar duas `DbContext`...

Comment: Você tem que criar outro DbContext! Cada um no seu quadrado.

Comment: Até hoje o único jeito que eu consegui trabalhar nesse cenário foi abandonando o EF e escrevendo todo o CRUD sql na mão mesmo. As bases estando no mesmo servidor e a conexão com um usuário que tenha acesso há todas você não precisaria de mais de um contexto